# PHP for loop on a ZIP folder insert two times the data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, php-ziparchive

I have a slight issue with a PHP code. I am trying to parse an online ZIP folder and insert data in a MySQL database. When parsing the folder, and getting information about the different single files, the PHP FOR loop seems to work properly when echoing data. However, when inserting data into my database, all information are inserted two times.

More precisely, there are 5109 files in the folder (echoed with $zip->numFiles) but in total 10218 (the double) rows are entered into the MySql table.

Please find below the code.

```
<?php
include('bdd-connexion.php');
$file = 'http://folder.zip';
$file = trim($file);
$newfile = 'folder.zip';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
 echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}

$zip = new ZipArchive();

if ($zip->open($newfile)!==TRUE) {
 exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
} else {
 echo "number of files => ".$zip->numFiles."<br>";

 for ($i=1; $i <= $zip->numFiles ; $i++) {
  echo $i."<br>"; // this echo is working properly
  $sql = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO database(uid) VALUES (:uid)");
  $sql->execute(array('uid' => 'test'));

}

?>
```

Thanks a lot.

Have a good day.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you only need to prepare the statement once, not every time through the loop.

Comment: There's no way that this code is inserting twice, you must be running it twice. Check your access log to see how many times the script is being run.

Comment: My guess is you're calling the script with AJAX, but you're not preventing normal form submission, which is also running the script.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for the comment regarding the prepation of the statement. Regarding the access log, I do have two entries when I am opening the webpage with the script: `[28/Apr/2020:13:04:27 +0200] "GET script.php HTTP/1.1" 200 41053` AND `[28/Apr/2020:13:04:33 +0200] "HEAD script.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: After checking, I have this issue only in localhost. The same script works properly online. If someone has an idea why I do have this issue in localhost (using Wampserver). Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is working also properly in localhost using Firefox instead of Chrome, or the Chrome's private browing option.

Comment: I'm not sure why Chrome would be sending `HEAD` requests, I've never seen that before. I suspect it has something to do with getting cache-related headers, maybe your localhost server isn't sending them in the `GET` response.

Comment: I do not know either.. I'll use the private browing opion of Chrome. Thank you very much for your help.